# Help understanding sequence proof involving lim sup.

Tags: real-analysis

I am reading Steven R. Lay's "Analysis with an introduction to proof". The theorem is,

"Suppose that $(r_n)$ converges to a positive number $r$ and that $(s_n)$ is a bounded sequence. Then,

$$ lim~sup~r_n s_n = r\cdot~lim~sup~s_n$$"

Proof:

Let $s = lim~sup~s_n$, and $t = lim~sup~r_n s_n$. Since $(s_n)$ is bounded, there exists a subsequence $(s_{n_k})$ of $(s_n)$ such that $(s_{n_k}) \rightarrow s$. Also, since $(r_n)$ converges to $r$, it is also bounded and therefore a subsequence exists $(r_{n_k})$ that also converges to $r$.

It follows by the "algebra of limits" that

$$ lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}~(r_{n_k})(s_{n_k}) = rs$$.

Hence $rs\leq t$.

This is the first part of the theorem, the second part is clear to me, and simply establishes that $rs \geq t$. I understand everything above, except why is it true that $rs\leq t$. This part is not immediately obvious to me (nor is it "not immediately obvious" as the case seems to be). I do know one or two lim sup theorems, however nothing that I can think to apply to this problem/derive the above fact. Any hints would therefore be appreciated.

Comment: $t$ is the largest limit point of $(r_ns_n)$.

Answer (score 1):

This follows from the fact that if $t=\limsup a_n$ and $a_{k_n}\to a$ then $a\leq t$.

I'd like to mention that this proof is a bit weird. I'm talking about te sentence

> Since $(r_n)$ converges to $r$, it is also bounded and therefore a
> subsequence exists $(r_{n_k})$ that also converges to $r$.

The reasoning is the following: the sequence is convergent, so the sequence is bounded, so the sequence has a convergent subsequence (by Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem).

This is crazy. Second thing is that the indeces $n_k$ defining this subsequence are magically the same as previously fixed by defining the sequence $(s_{n_k})$.

There should be: Since $(r_n)$ converges to $r$, its subsequence $(r_{n_k})$  also converges to $r$.